# Use grep to find strings with consecutive same letters

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

How to use grep -iE to find strings with 2 groups of consecutive same letters. The 2 groups do not overlap. Only grep e is allowed.

Comment: It would be supportive if you could paste what you have tried and also some strings that you are matching against with the expected output. Until then, I am voting to close this question.

Comment: You mean `grep -iE`, right? Options `e` and `E` mean totally different things.

Comment: @rici 22 yes i mean grep -iE

Comment: I already found the answer : grep -iE '([a-z])\1.*([a-z])\2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

already found the answer:

```
grep -iE '([a-z])\1.*([a-z])\2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match the *first* occurrence of the duplicate with this:

```
(.+)(?=.*\1)
```

This uses a look-ahead for another copy using a back reference to the captured group.

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/qiOAdwY0WC).

Comment: With this approach, in `fooabcbarabc`, the `b` will matched the followed `a` in `bar` between two `abc`.

Comment: Look-aheads are not available in grep without the -P option